# SAPUI5 router error

Tags: routes, sapui5

I have an error when I pass parameters from a view controller to another view controller. The variable id is undefined.

Recive controller

```
var oParameters = oEvent.getParameters();

alert(oParameters.arguments.id);
alert(oParameters.arguments.entity);
```

Pass controller

```
var bReplace = jQuery.device.is.phone ? false : true;
    var context  = {
        entity: "EmployeeCollection",
        id:  "1"
    };
    this.getRouter().myNavBack("detail", context, bReplace);
```

The parameter entity works.

Thanks.

Comment: from what you've posted, there seems to be no issue. can you post a working code snippet?

Comment: Are you sure that the context-Data are passed by Event-Parameters? Try to inspect the oEvent-Data by setting a debugger;-Statement in the Eventhandler-Function

Answer (score 0):

First of all I suggest you to use the public API to get the arguments, because this way you are safe in case some UI5 internals change (just in case you are not doing it this way):

```
var oArgs = oEvent.getParameter("arguments");
```

Other than that, could you please post your routing configuration? I'm interested in the corresponding route pattern. In your case you can only access "entity" if it's part of your route's pattern, and it has to be a [mandatory parameter](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/f96d2522a5ca4382a274ae3c6d002ca0.html) in your case. In this case you would access it like this:

```
var sEntity = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").entity;
```

If "entity" shall be a query parameter, then your code would look slightly different:

```
var bReplace = jQuery.device.is.phone ? false : true;
var context  = {
    id:  "1",
    query : {
        entity: "EmployeeCollection",
    }
};
this.getRouter().myNavBack("detail", context, bReplace);
```

And this is how you would get the query parameter in your (how you call it) "receiving" controller:

```
var oArgs = oEvent.getParameter("arguments");
var oQuery = oArgs["?query"];
var sEntity = oQuery.entity;
```

I think more details check the official [Navigation & Routing Tutorial - Step 9](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/b8561ff6f4c34c85a91ed06d20814cd3.html).

Also keep in mind that you have not posted the code of your own myNavBack() function. Maybe there is something wrong in there, but nobody know unless you post the code ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My Component config:
   routes: [{
    pattern: "",
    name: "main",
    view: "Master",
    targetAggregation: "masterPages",
    targetControl: "idAppControl",
    subroutes: [
     {
     pattern: "EmployeeCollection{entity}",
     name: "detail",
     view: "Detail",
     transition:"slide"
    },
    {
     pattern : "PlaceCollection{entity}",
     name : "stationDetail",
     view : "StationDetail",
     transition:"slide"
    },
    {
     pattern : "VehicleCollection{entity}",
     name : "trainDetail",
     view : "TrainDetail",
     transition:"slide"
    }]

Comment: Ooops, it seems you are using the "old" and kinda "deprecated" routing configuration! What version of UI5 are you using? Is your app a new app or some "old" app that you need to maintain? Anyway,... The Navigation & Routing Tutorial describes the latest APIs and the new and definitely preferred routing configuration, including targets. You are using the "old way" (i.e. subroutes are not used in the "new" routing...). I suggest you to migrate. But first read the tutorial :-)
Another question: could you give an example of how a hash for the pattern "EmployeeCollection{entity}" could look like?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this class is generated by WebIDE template. I don't edit this class. I look the tutorial to compare the routers.
Thanks and regards.